# How to have a click for div element in angualr2

Tags: html, angular, angularjs-ng-click

I have a div which should have a click event , I have tried as below

```
<div class="panel-body"  (Click)="onDivClick()"></div>
```

But it's not working

Comment: Could you try it with `(click)="onDivClick()"`?

Comment: Did ng-click didn't work ?

Answer (score 2):

Templates in Angular2 are case sensitive. Instead of `(Click)` use `(click)`